# A path for building a website

Tags: web-services, google-maps, web

I would like to ask a question about building a website. When someone opens the website, s/he will see a world which is a 3D sphere model and the google maps placed onto it. It's exactly the same model that google earth have used (but the main problem is google is not supporting the google earth project for API' s and stuff, and it's deprecated right now). Furthermore I would like to place a little eiffel tower onto france on the world, so when one zooms in, it will appear and grow bigger.

The exact question is, which path should I follow to achieve these goals. What kind of programming languages or frameworks should I learn for it? I know that it is a VERY long process but I have no clue about where to begin and need a proper advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: mianly  javascript .. (google-maps is in javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://cesiumjs.org/

If Google don't provide alternative to deprecated version then there isn't google alternative to 3d in js. If you think why so many developer like google api then because is simple, free for small-medium project and they have great quality in what they do.

What you can do is learn:
HTML
CSS
JS
WebGL

Backend like PHP or ASP isn't nesesery, because you can use Node.js.

Create basic thing, practice - don't read book. They are great but time consuming and you won't remember so much than doing something and experience. There is of course live world where bugs and problem exist so book aren't best way to learn in programming.

Websites are generally easy to create but hard to perfect.

My summary of problem: Use libraries, edit them, play with them. Use snippets and after some time dig deeper in it. This approach give you faster result, better code and give you willingness to take on next task.